# How to create a hyper link inside ExtJS label

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my ExtJs app I need to show a message with a hyperlink like the following:

> A license is required to enable the feature. See [Licenses](http://www.example.com) for
>   more information.

I'm trying to use ExtJS Label component, however I have no idea how to create a link inside the label's text. The general problem is the link should have `onclick` Javascript handler.

Should I use Label's `html` option to set both plain html text and Javascript handler, or is there another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`html`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-html) config for creating the link and event delegation for adding the click listener.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    html: 'A license is required to enable the feature. See <a href="#">Licenses</a> for more information.',
    listeners: {
        'click': function() {
            // do stuff
        },
        // name of the component property which refers to the element to add the listener to
        element: 'el',
        // css selector to filter the target element
        delegate: 'a'
    }
});
```

Also see [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mon).

The options are explained in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-on):

> - element : String
>
>   This option is only valid for listeners bound to Components. The name of a Component property which references an element to add a listener to.
>
>   This option is useful during Component construction to add DOM event listeners to elements of Components which will exist only after the Component is rendered.
>
>   [...]
> - delegate : String (optional)
>
>   A simple selector to filter the event target or look for a descendant of the target.
>
>   The "delegate" option is only available on Ext.dom.Element instances (or when attaching a listener to a Ext.dom.Element via a Component using the element option).
>
>   [...]

Note that I used `Ext.Component` instead of `Ext.Label`. In case you really need the functionality of `Ext.Label` (it's intended for usage in combination with form fields) you can just change that.

Comment: Ext can handle the extra logic to register on the element with the syntax `listeners: {el: {delegate: 'a', click: handler}}`. See [updated fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mou). Also, I would let the real url in the link href, for browser usability reasons.

Comment: @rixo Can you please tell where these syntaxes are mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: No, sorry, I can't find it. I thought it would have been [there](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-addListener), but apparently it is not. I must have seen it in a blog post. There's the `element` option that is close, so now the official way would be `element: 'el'` instead of the nested `el` syntax.

Comment: Thanks rixo for pointing this out, I've updated my answer and fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll be better to use the `html` option since you need to render a link as well. As for the event handling, one way is to attach an event handler and check if the target `node` in the `dom` is that anchor.

Please check this [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/moj) for clarification.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title:'Label with link',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'label',
            forId: 'myFieldId',
            html: '<p>This is a test for <a href="#">link</a> in label</p>',
            margin: '0 0 0 10',
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    element: 'el',
                    preventDefault: true,
                    fn: function(e, target){
                        var el = Ext.fly(target);
                        if(el.dom.nodeName === "A"){
                            console.log('Clicked');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]

    });
```